# Как мне отправить значение radio на сервер?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```js
    function fun1() {
    var rad=document.getElementsByName('r1');
                               
    for (var i=0; i<rad.length; i++) {
     if (rad[i].checked) {
    //a = +i+;
     $.ajax({
     url: "/cpa.php",
     type: 'post',
    data: {"r1": a},
    success: function(){
    alert(i);
    }
});
 }                      
      };}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="1">Визиты<br>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="2">Заявки<br>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="3">Договора<br>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="4">Контрольные оплаты<br>
<button onclick="fun1()">Проверить, какой из элементов выбран</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), чтобы отправить данные из формы на сервер, например так:

```js
$("#theForm").submit(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault(); // отменяем действие отправки формы по умолчанию.

  var form = $(this);
  var url = form.attr('action');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: form.serialize(), // Сериализация полей формы
    success: function(data) {
      // функционал в случае успеха
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      // функционал в случае ошибки
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="theForm" action="http://pathserver">
  <input type="radio" name="r1" value="1">Визиты<br>
  <input type="radio" name="r1" value="2">Заявки<br>
  <input type="radio" name="r1" value="3">Договора<br>
  <input type="radio" name="r1" value="4">Контрольные оплаты<br>
  <button type="submit">Проверить, какой из элементов выбран</button>
</form>
```